# Laravel FormRequest validation for dynamic rows

Tags: php, laravel, validation, message, laravel-formrequest

I have a form with dynamics rows. I would like to use FormRequest to validate data rows. How to achieve it ?

Form

```php
<td>
   <input class="form-control form-control-sm" id="item_quantity" type="number" step="any" min="0" name="item_quantity[]" value="{{old('item_quantity[]')}}"> 
   {!!$errors->first('item_quantity', '<span class="error">:message</span>')!!}
</td>
```

My FormRequest Code :

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'item_quantity' => 'required'
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1: Do you save it as array or per row?

you can pass only required data as validated by form by adding required at end of input.

```
<td>
   <input class="form-control form-control-sm" id="item_quantity" type="number" step="any" min="0" name="item_quantity[]" value="{{old('item_quantity[]')}}" required=""> 
   {!!$errors->first('item_quantity', '<span class="error">:message</span>')!!}
</td>
```

if this does not work, please lets know how you save your data as per question 1 above.

Comment: Thks MR. VIN for your answer... Adding "required" help me to validate input but i can't translate error message. I use Localization to translate my form.

Comment: do you still get an error? if yes which error?

Comment: No... Error just occur when there is an error.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i made these modifications and its works:

Form

```
<td><input class="form-control form-control-sm" id="item_quantity" type="number" step="any" min="0" name="item_quantity[]" value="{{old('item_quantity[]')}}">{!!$errors->first('item_quantity.*', '<span class="error">:message</span>')!!}</td>
```

FormRequest

```
public function rules(){return ['item_quantity.*' => 'required'];}
```

Thks for your helps !